# How to pass data from javascript to python?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file, on click of a submit button i need to pass user information to my python exe?

From the python exe i need to load and a call a function in my vc++ dll?

Please provide me your valuable inputs?

Comment: Does this need to by asynchronous or will a normal POST form suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Er - is this in a browser context? I apologize if not..

You'd probably need to use `XMLHttpRequest` to make an HTTP request to your server-side script and pass variables either through `GET` or `POST`.

See http://xkr.us/code/javascript/XHConn/ for a decent minimal cross-browser script.